# How to properly validate virtual attributes, date field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

Everything is working except validation,. I want to validate this properly: I have 2 fields that is mapped in one attribute in a model. For this case I have start_at and end_at, each have 2 fields. Also I want to handle nil input (ArgumentError).

Here is my code:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    #VIRTUAL ATTRIBUTES
    attr_accessor :start_date, :start_time, :end_date, :end_time

    #RELATIONSHIPS
    belongs_to :task

    #VALIDATIONS

    before_save :convert_to_datetime

    def start_date
        start_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") if start_at.present?

    end 

    def start_time
        start_at.strftime("%I:%M%p") if start_at.present?
    end

    def start_date=(date)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  @start_date =  Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
end

def start_time=(time)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  @start_time = Time.parse(time).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

end

def end_date
    end_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") if end_at.present?
end 

def end_time
    end_at.strftime("%I:%M%p") if end_at.present?
end

def end_date=(date)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  @end_date = Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
end

def end_time=(time)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  @end_time = Time.parse(time).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
end

def convert_to_datetime
    self.start_at = DateTime.parse("#{@start_date} #{@start_time}")
    self.end_at = DateTime.parse("#{@end_date} #{@end_time}")
end

end
```

Strong params:

```
params.require(:task).permit(:category_id, :subcategory_id, :title, :description, :pay_offer, :pay_type, :county_id, :area_id, appointments_attributes: [:id, :start_date, :start_time, :end_date, :end_time])
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [before_validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback instead of before_save.
In that case you can do validations on start_at and end_at, which are normal attributes. You probably want a [presence validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence).

Validations would look something like this:

```
validates :start_at, presence: true
validates :end_at, presence: true
```

UPDATE:

You will also have to make sure you don't try to parse blank string.

```
def start_date=(date)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  unless date.blank?
    @start_date =  Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
  end
end

def start_time=(time)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  unless time.blank?
    @start_time = Time.parse(time).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end
end

def end_date=(date)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  unless date.blank?
    @end_date = Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
  end
end

def end_time=(time)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  unless time.blank?
    @end_time = Time.parse(time).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end
end
```

UPDATE 2:

```
 unless @start_date.blank? && @start_time.blank? && @end_date.blank? && @end_time.blank?
        self.start_at = DateTime.parse("#{@start_date} #{@start_time}")

        self.end_at = DateTime.parse("#{@end_date} #{@end_time}")
    end
```

Comment: hi @Dabrorius, Ive been doing that, but it just gives me an error: 
ArgumentError in TasksController#create
invalid date.........  LOG:  "appointments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"start_date"=>"",
 "start_time"=>"",
 "end_date"=>"",
 "end_time"=>""}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Task"}

Comment: That's because you are passing blank strings to strptime, I have updated my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Dabrorius, I also added unless statement in private methods, it is workinng now. Thank you so much for you help! really appreciate it man!